# writing to file not displaying everything c++

Tags: c++

not sure where im going wrong
I am trying to write to a file in c++.

this is the code:

```
struct Student {
   int id;
   std::string name;
    double mark;
   double priority;

   bool operator < (const Student & s) const {
      return (priority < s.priority);
   }
   void print() const {
   std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("result.txt",std::ios::out);
   myfile << "id: (";
    myfile<< id;
    myfile << ") ";
    myfile<<"name: ";
    myfile<< name;
    myfile << " : ";
    myfile<< " Priority value: ";
    myfile << priority;
    myfile <<"\n";
//  myfile.close();
    std::cout << "name: " << id << ") " << name << " : " << " Priority value: " << priority << std::endl;
   }
};

   void printPriorityQ(std::priority_queue < Student > q) {
      while (!q.empty()) {
         q.top().print();
         q.pop();
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
```

I can successfully output the content of the priority queue to the console but am struggling to output it to the result.txt file

my current output in result.txt is it prints the last item and stops

for example my console will show

> name: (1) bob: priority value: 5

> name: (2) jen: priority value: 4

> name: (3) james: priority value: 3

and my txt file will display

> name: (3) james: priority value: 3

Edit: tried the comment and changed `ios::out` to `ios::app`
i found that it would append the file which i didnt want.
after looking online i used the `ios::trunc` instead but that gives me the same problem as before

Comment: Open the file in append (`app`) mode, not output mode. Don't have time to explain the details now so won't make it a full answer.

Comment: thankyou, this actually appends the current file. when i use "trunc" instead i get the same problem that it only prints 1 item

Comment: @william_ what exactly do you want your output to look like? Your question suggests it should contain all entries of your priority queue

Comment: yes correct it should contain all entries 
when i use ios::trunc to overwrite the existing file (which is what i want) it will only print out one entry. when i use ios::app it prints all entries but i dont want it to append. Eventually the files will be placed on an online directory to be downloaded so i cant append the files

Comment: Could you show us what the file looks like after ios::app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue in yor current code is that the `print()` function is overwriting the output file each time it is called.

One possible solution that doesn't require you to use ios::app is to change the signature of the function as follows:

```
void print(std::ofstream& myfile ) const {
    myfile << "id: (";
    myfile<< id;
    myfile << ") ";
    myfile<<"name: ";
    myfile<< name;
    myfile << " : ";
    myfile<< " Priority value: ";
    myfile << priority;
    myfile <<"\n";
    std::cout << "name: " << id << ") " << name << " : " << " Priority value: " << priority << std::endl;
   }
```

and open the file before the loop begins, such that the file is created only once:

```
   void printPriorityQ(std::priority_queue < Student > q) {
      std::ofstream outputFile("result.txt");
      while (!q.empty()) {
         q.top().print(outputFile);
         q.pop();
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
```

This should solve your issue. Notice however that this will cause the file "result.txt" to be overwritten every time `printPriorityQ` is called, for the same reasons as above. An even better solution could be using a `std::ofstream&` reference as an input parameter for `printPriorityQ` too.